# Search for multiple values within MySQL issue

Tags: mysql, search

I am trying to search for two keywords within the data table, but am running into issues where  the following returns no resolutes even through I know there are about 36.

Can somebody help me write a better query?

```
SELECT user_id, name, value
FROM data
    INNER JOIN fields ON data.field_id = fields.id 
WHERE name IN ('Type', 'Category')
AND value = 'Keyword 1'
AND value = 'Keyword 2'  /* If I use OR it returns 50 records of those +14 are irrelevant*/
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id)>1
ORDER BY value
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Note the addition of the parentheses:

```
SELECT user_id, name, value
FROM data
INNER JOIN fields ON data.field_id = fields.id 
WHERE name IN ('Type', 'Category')
AND (value = 'Keyword 1'
OR value = 'Keyword 2') 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id)>1
ORDER BY value
```

SQL binds from left to right, so

```
WHERE name IN ('Type', 'Category') AND value = 'Keyword 1' OR value = 'Keyword 2'
```

is equivalent to

```
WHERE (name IN ('Type', 'Category') AND value = 'Keyword 1') OR value = 'Keyword 2'
```

so you can see where the extra records came from — all records with `value = 'Keyword 2'` will be included irrespective of `name`.

Of course, you could also write:

```
WHERE name IN ('Type', 'Category') AND value IN ('Keyword 1', 'Keyword 2')
```

which eliminates the precedence issue.

Comment: Thanks Larry have just tested option 4 and is working well. Except that I am now realising that if lets say a user has two records of  'Keyword 1' but not 'Keyword 2' it still gets added to the query.<br/><br/>Is there anyway to make the query only return records that have 'Keyword 1' and 'Keyword 2' from both name fields?

Comment: Most likely yes, but you'll have to state more clearly what records you want returned.  My suggestion is to post a new question and include some sample input records and show what results you expect from that input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the conditions like this:

```
WHERE name IN ('Type', 'Category')
AND (value = 'Keyword 1'
    OR value = 'Keyword 2' )
```

Otherwise MySql will return rows that have Keyword 2 but their name is not Type or Category.

Alternatively, look into [Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Yeah Full-Text Search is a little over my head :) Thanks for the link

Comment: @thisisnousername check my variation for this answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT user_id, name, value
FROM data
    INNER JOIN fields ON data.field_id = fields.id 
WHERE name IN ('Type', 'Category')
AND value in( 'Keyword 1','Keyword 2') 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id)>1
ORDER BY value
```